# How to extract data from an object, into Apollo Query component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

Trying to extract data from a graphql API and can't use `map()` since the data is being returned as an object.
I am getting the desired results on Apollo server (based on my schema) though.

This is what I am getting after executing the code:
`data.getRandomMeal.map is not a function`

On debugging, it says `data = { getRandomMeal {...} }`

```
<Query
  query={
    gql`{
      getRandomMeal {
        idMeal
        strMeal
      }
    }`
  }
>
  {({ data }) => { 
    if (data === undefined) return null; 
    return (
      <ul>
        {data.getRandomMeal && data.getRandomMeal.map(meal => (
          <li key={meal.idMeal}>{meal.strMeal} </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }}
</Query>
```

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Meal{
    idMeal: ID
    strMeal: String
    strTags: String
    strCategory: String
  }

  type Query {
    getRandomMeal: Meal
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getRandomMeal: async (_, __, { dataSources }) =>
      dataSources.RandomRecipe.getRandomMeal()
  }
};
```

Datasource:

```
class RandomRecipe extends RESTDataSource{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.baseURL = 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php'; 
  }

  async getRandomMeal(){
    const meal = await this.get('/');
    return meal.meals[0];
  }
};

module.exports = RandomRecipe;
```

Comment: provide data sample

Comment: I have added some info. Hopefully useful.

Comment: it's not graphql api - try `console.log( data.getRandomMeal )` - maybe you need a query `getRandomMeal.{ meals { idMeal ...`

Comment: `console.log( data.getRandomMeal )` returns undefined. Adjusting the query crushes the server. All was going smoothly till this point °_°

Comment: `console.log(data)`? provide typdefs/schema and resolvers`

Comment: Done. See edits...

Comment: `await this.get(this.baseURL);`, not `await this.get('/');`

Comment: Changed, thanks. How to get rid of  `data.getRandomMeal.map is not a function`?

Comment: just remove it - `data.getRandomMeal` is your data object

Comment: Like a charm. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const meal = await this.get('/');`

in connection with

`this.baseURL = 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php';`

results with incorrect URL

`'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php/'`

It should be sufficient to use empty string in

`const meal = await this.get('');`

Response can be used directly, without using map:

```
    {({ data })  => {

      if (data === undefined) return null; 
      const meal = data.getRandomMeal;

      return (
        <ul>
          {meal && (
            <li key={meal.idMeal}>{meal.strMeal} </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      );
    }}
```